# [Verification]Let H be a subgroup of G and $N = \bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$. Prove that N is a subgroup of G and that $aNa^{-1} = N$ for all $a \in G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification

Let $H$ be a subgroup of $G$ and $$N = \bigcap_{x\in G} xHx^{-1}$$. Prove that $N$ is a subgroup of $G$ and that $aNa^{-1} = N$ for all $a \in G$.

Proof:

$1 = x1x^{-1}$ for all $x \in G$ . Hence $1 \in N$.
For all $xhx^{-1} \in xHx^{-1}$, $(xhx^{-1})^{-1} = xhx^{-1} \in xHx^{-1}$. Hence, for all $y \in N, y^{-1} \in N$. For all $x, y \in N, x = x_1h_1x_1^{-1} = x_2h_2x_2^{-1} = ...$ and y = $x_1h'_1x_1^{-1} = x_2h'_2x_2^{-1} = ... \in N$. Hence, $xy =x_1h_1h'_1x_1^{-1} = x_2h_2h'_2x_2^{-1} = ... \in N$. Therefore, N is a subgroup of G.

To prove that $aNa^{-1} = N$. First prove that $xHx^{-1}$ is also a subgroup. Then, for all $y \in N$, $y = x_1h_1x_1^{-1} = x_2h_2x_2^{-1} = ...$. Note that $ax_1 \neq ax_2 \neq ax_3 \neq ...$, else $x_i = x_j$ by cancellation law. Define a function $f := x \to ax$. It is obvious that this function is both injective and surjective. Therefore, $|x| = |ax|$ and each $xH(x)^{-1}, x\in G $ must contain $(ax_i)H(ax_i)^{-1}$  for some $i \in \mathbb{N}$. Therefore, y is in the intersection of all $xHx^{-1}, x\in G$. Hence, $aNa^{-1} = N$.

Comment: $|x| = |ax|$ is not true in general, take $x = a^{-1}.$ (by $|x|$ you mean order, I assume!) Also $G$ is not given countable, so $x = x_1h_1x_1^{-1} = x_2h_2x_2^{-1} = ...$ can't cover all $x \in G.$

Comment: @Krish actually what i am trying to say is that the number of elements in the domain and codomain is equal. Is this claim false as well?

Answer (score 3):

*Hint:* For each $x \in G, xHx^{-1}$ is a subgroup of $G.$ Now show that intersection of (any number of) subgroups is again a subgroup of $G.$ This will prove that $N$ is a subgroup of $G.$ Fix $a \in G.$ Now define a function $f: G \to G, x \mapsto ax.$ This is a bijection. Hence $\{xHx^{-1}: x \in G \} = \{(ax)H(ax)^{-1} : x \in G \}.$

*Note:* This proof is essentially the one that you wrote in the question. I rewrite it to avoid some confusion (which was there). Your idea was correct, but needed a little argument to clarify some points.